# Error reading sas metadata file through package haven R

Tags: r, databricks, r-haven

I am using haven library to read SAS file metadata from a sas7bdat file. Following is the code used by me

```
library(haven)
sas_file <- read_sas("/dbfs/mnt/test1/Disease/Heart Attack/SAS/airline.sas7bdat", 
                     catalog_file = "/dbfs/mnt/test1/Disease/Heart Attack/SAS/airline.sas7bdat")
```

I am getting following error after this:

> "Error in df_parse_sas_file(spec_data, spec_cat, encoding = encoding, catalog_encoding = catalog_encoding, :"

Please guide me through how to resolve this. Both the files are pointing to same location as single file contain data as well as metadata when I view in sas viewer.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using the `catalog` option, that's not a catalog - that's for things like an associated format catalog.  That's not definitely causing the error (I tested a similar syntax and it didn't error), but it's definitely wrong.